# What lifts shouldn't I do with a posterior labrum tear?

Tags: weightlifting, injury, injury-prevention

I have a posterior labral tear. What lifts shouldn't I do with it? Can I do curls, pull ups, triceps extentions,  pullovers... etc? I have been benching on the floor, as I hear the elbow shouldn't go behind the back with the tear.

Comment: What does your physical therapist/doctor say?

Comment: I agree with @John.  Your medical team should be directing your rehab, not people on a site with no knowledge of your orthopedic evaluation.

Answer (score 3):

**What lifts shouldn't you do when suffering a muscle tear, cartilage tear, soft tissue damage, hard tissue damage or broken bone?**

Well, until your doctor says otherwise, I'd stay away from:

- Deadlifts
- Squats
- Bench press
- Overhead press
- Bicep curls
- Tricep curls
- Quadricep curls
- The frequently unheard of Quinrecp, Hexacep and Septecep curls
- Running, jogging, walking faster than an elderly person with a zimmer frame

I'd also steer clear of Barbells, dumbbells, kettlebells and churchbells.

Maybe just stick to bench squats, preferably performed on your couch, at a cadence of 5-seconds down, the length of Arnold Schwarzenegger's Pumping Iron in the low position and 5-seconds back to the starting position.

Comment: muscle tear? the labrum isn't a muscle

Comment: So it seems you have stumbled upon the exact reason why getting medical advice over the internet is risky business.

Comment: @GeoreShg - So...the entire sarcasm of the post goes over your head and you focus on a misworded title? Your question is off topic and asking for medical advice. Offering a bounty on a bad question won't help anything.